# Showing $ (R ∪ R^{-1})^∗ = R^∗ ∪ R^{−1∗} $ is false by giving a counterexample.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

> Show that $$
> (R ∪ R^{-1})^∗ = R^∗ ∪ R^{−1∗}
> $$ is false by giving a counterexample.

I tried the following, but every time it keeps coming out as true (instead of false):

If $R = \{(a,b), (a,c)\}$. Then $R^{-1}$ will be $\{(b,a), (c,a)\}$. 
The union will give: $\{(a,b), (a,c), (b,a), (c,a)\}$. With the ${}^*$, it will be:  $\{(a,b), (a,c), (b,a), (c,a), (a,a), (b,b), (c,c)\}$.

Same goes for the right side:
$R^*$ will in this case be $\{(a,b), (a,c), (a,a), (b,b), (c,c)\}$. So $R^{-1} = \{(b,a), (c,a)\}$. So the union will be $\{(a,b), (a,c), (b,a), (c,a), (a,a), (b,b), (c,c)\}$.

Which means that it is true (left and right side are equal to each other).

However, when is this false?

Comment: What is $R^\ast$? Is it $\Delta \cup R  \cup R^2 \cup \dotsc$ or $R\cup R^2 \cup R^3\cup \dotsc$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Thank you for your comments both! Shaun, that is a nice link I bookmarked for future posts! Very handy!
Daniel Fischer, interesting. I thought it was the elements that make a relation reflexive including the elements that are already in there. I would choose the left one. But I'm not sure at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your own example is indeed a counterexample, if you work it out correctly! $(b,c) = (b,a)(a,c)$ is in $(R\cup R^{-1})^*$, but in neither $R^*$ nor $(R^{-1})^*$. (Same with $(c,b)$.)

(In the future, you should remember to define your notation in your questions. It's not clear just from the typographical symbols that $S^*$ is supposed to signify the relation generated by $S$. Indeed, I'm just guessing with the above answer that that's your intent.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So transitivity plays a role in this case? 
I still can't understand why (b,c) isn't in $ R^* $ nor $ (R^{-1})^* $. But that means that either (b,a), (a,c) or both are not in there.

Comment: Not exactly. $(b,a)$ is indeed in $(R^{-1})^*$, and $(a,c)$ is indeed in $R^*$. But there's no reason that the set $R^*\cup(R^{-1})^*$ needs to satisfy transitivity (it's not the ${}^*$ of anything, for example). So the fact that that set contains both $(b,a)$ and $(a,c)$ says nothing about whether it contains $(b,c)$.